# Unable to tab out from UltraCombo control, when control data bindings Value, Text properties with null data source

Tags: winforms, infragistics, ultracombo

In my project, I have `INGRAGISTICS 11.1` version. I’m getting the issue in `UltraCombo` control. Unable to tab out from control.

When we try to find the cause, we observed that OnValidating is failing (always `e.cancel` = true is returning).

I have `XML` entity data binding, in my form.

Binding sample code:

```
this.cmbListC.DataBindings.Add("Value", xKey, "InnerXml");
this.cmbListC.DataBindings.Add("Text", xValue, "InnerXml");
```

Why always `e.cancel` is retuning true when data source is **null**.

Comment: What are the values for the properties AllowNull and LimitToList?

Comment: As Steve wrote, if LimitToList is set to true you need to set AllowNull to true too. Otherwise the validation of UltraCombo will fail, if the user did not choose any value.

Comment: we tried both the scenarios, but no luck.
we are facing the same issue.
please provide the solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not AllowNull or LimitToList, then most likely the data source is rejecting the change.

I'm not sure what xKey and xValue are, but it looks like you are binding both properties of the control to the same field in your data source, which presumably cannot contain two values at the same time without violating the laws of physics. Try binding one or the other and see if that corrects the issue.